# "template argument deduction/substitution failed:" error on using rclcpp::Node::create_wall_timer function

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

When using the rclcpp::Node::create_wall_timer function with std::bind , I am getting the following error

no matching function for call to ‘composition::Talker::create_wall_timer(std::chrono::seconds, std::_Bind_helper<false, void (composition::Talker::*)(int), composition::Talker*, int>::type)’

The error can be reproducer if one changes std::bind function inside  the create_wall_timer () to add extra arguments to the function pointer.

I am attaching the code for your kind reference.

```
#include "composition/talker_component.hpp"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

namespace composition
{

Talker::Talker()
: Node("talker"), count_(0)
{
  // Create a publisher of "std_mgs/String" messages on the "chatter" topic.
  pubbase_= this->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>("chatter");

  pub_ = create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>("chatter");
  timer_ = create_wall_timer(1s, std::bind(&Talker::on_timer, this,95));
 
}

void Talker::on_timer(int level)
{
  auto msg = std::make_shared<std_msgs::msg::String>();

  msg->data = "Hello World: " + std::to_string(++count_);

  // Put the message into a queue to be processed by the middleware.
 
  // This call is non-blocking.
  pub_->publish(msg);
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288759/%22template-argument-deduction/substitution-failed:%22-error-on-using-rclcpp::node::create_wall_timer-function/) by [Skyking](https://answers.ros.org/users/31939/skyking/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2018-04-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-04-16**:
@Skyking please don't use the backtick formatting for code blocks. This is for single code Statements.

Just Highlight the copy-pasted code block and click the preformatted text button (the one with 10101010) on it. Thanks.

**Comment by [Skyking](https://answers.ros.org/users/31939/skyking/) on 2018-04-17**:
Thanks @mig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are some [limitations on automatic type deduction of custom callbacks](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/273) that can be worked around by explicitly declaring the `std::function`, e.g.:

```
  std::function<void()> callback_func = std::bind(&Talker::on_timer, this, 95);
  timer_ = create_wall_timer(1s, callback_func);
```

Or if you want to pass a variable in you might use `std::cref` in place of the `95`.

---

Originally posted by [dhood](https://answers.ros.org/users/18823/dhood/) with karma: 621 on 2018-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0